# Template not rendering correctly while iterating through foreign keys

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to iterate over my FKs in my model such that I show all the connections through various tables. My template renders but does not show any values. Any ideas?

models.py

```
class State(models.Model):
   state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
   relevantoption = models.ManyToManyField(Option, through='StateOption')

class StateOption(models.Model):
   partstate = models.ForeignKey(State)
   partoption = models.ForeignKey(Option)
   relevantoutcome = models.ManyToManyField(Outcome, through='StateOptionOutcome')

class StateOptionOutcome(models.Model):
   stateoption = models.ForeignKey(StateOption)
   relevantoutcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcome)
   outcomevalue = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

views.py

```
def stateall(request, disease_id):

    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)  
    states = State.objects.select_related().filter(relevantdisease=disease_id)

    context = {'disease':disease,'states': states}
    return render(request, "stateall.html", context)
```

template.html

```
{% for state in states %}
    <li>{% for i in state.stateoption_set.all %}</li>
        <li>{% for j in i.stateoptionoutcome_set.all %}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I would like the template to show up as:

```
State1<state>
   <li>partoption</li>
      <li>relevantoutcome: outcomevalue</li>

State2<state>
    <li>partoption</li>
      <li>relevantoutcome: outcomevalue</li>

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template never outputs anything.

You're probably misunderstanding the use of the `{% for %}` template  tag.

This:

```
<li>{% for j in i.stateoptionoutcome_set.all %}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Outputs `<li>` a few times.

But this:

```
{% for j in i.stateoptionoutcome_set.all %}
    <li>{{ j.relevantoutcome }}: {{ j.outcomevalue }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Will output a line per `StateOptionOutcome` found in `i.stateoptionoutcome_set.all`.